# saturation, banked register, ARM, flag Q

Tags: arm

First question:

ARMv5TE, ARMv6 and later have a Q flag that is set to 1 when saturation has occurred in saturating arithmetic instructions, or when overflow has occurred in certain multiply instructions.

What is the saturation?

Second one:

What is banked register?

Comment: ask only one thing at a time. Explanation for banked registers can be easier be found on google, if you still have doubt, ask another question

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Saturation happens when the result of an operation does not fit in the available size. For example, assuming we add 32-bit unsigned numbers 0xF000_0000 + 0x2000_0000:

1. Standard addition   => 0x1_1000_0000 (truncation) => 0x1000_0000
2. Saturating addition => 0x1_1000_0000 (saturation) => 0xFFFF_FFFF